# Query with foward-slash (/) in a string

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run a query in MySql to replace a part of a params string (text type) containing a slash (/) to some joomla items menu.

eg: Fitness/sport is a part of string that  I need to change to Fitness & Sport

in the table the string is write by joomla like this:

......................

"page_title":"Vicenza Fitness/Sport",

......................

first I tried to select:

```
select id,params FROM  mytable WHERE params LIKE '%Fitness/Sport%';
```

then I tried to replace directly

```
UPDATE mytable SET params = REPLACE(params,'Fitness/Sport','Fitness & Sport') WHERE alias ='fitness-sport';
```

but both querys returns 0 results.

(I have 139 rows containig abc/xyz per each alias)

as @Vladimir demonstrate the query normaly work with a foward slash and seaching only for it

```
select id,params FROM  mytable WHERE params LIKE '%/%';
```

the query work fine, and work, also, searching for a string without a slash
(I can't  query only for the foward-slash because it will affect other params strings)

I can't figure out why don't work,
 any suggestion ?

Thank's

Comment: It might be helpful if you  give some real examples of the contents of params

Comment: there is no row with `alias ='myalias'`?

Comment: Thank's for reply
"Params" is in a joomla menu and here is a short json rapresentation:
 "menu_show" : 1,
 "menu_text" : 1,
 "page_heading" : "Abruzzo",
 "page_title" : "Abruzzo Fitness/Sport",
 "pageclass_sfx" : "  Abruzzo  fitness-sport",
 "robots" : "",

and searching only for "myalias" the query return, 139 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I figure out what is wrong in the query;

I do not why but it seems that the foward-slash ( / ) is written into the table together with a back-slash and became ( / ) so I tried  to escape the back-slash and all work perfectly.

The right query is:

```
UPDATE mytable SET params = REPLACE(params,'Fitness\\/Sport','Fitness & Sport') WHERE alias ='fitness-sport'
```

Note the double back-slash for to escape.

Answer (score 0):

```
select REPLACE('string abc/xyz', 'abc/xyz','abc & xyz');
+--------------------------------------------------+
| REPLACE('string abc/xyz', 'abc/xyz','abc & xyz') |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| string abc & xyz                                 |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

It mean that replace clause works perfectly, but if you receive 0 it mean that you don't have row wit `params LIKE '%abc/xyz%' AND alias ='myalias'`, first query says exactly this.

Here my simple example:

```
cli [db]> create table simpleTest (id int key, params varchar(50) );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

cli [db]> insert into simpleTest values
    -> (1, 'params test abc/xyz 1'),
    -> (2, 'params test abc/xyz 2'),
    -> (3, 'params test abc/xyz 3');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

cli [db]> select * from simpleTest;
+----+-----------------------+
| id | params                |
+----+-----------------------+
|  1 | params test abc/xyz 1 |
|  2 | params test abc/xyz 2 |
|  3 | params test abc/xyz 3 |
+----+-----------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

cli [db]> update simpleTest set params = replace(params, 'abc/xyz', 'abc & xyz');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0

cli [db]> select * from simpleTest;
+----+-------------------------+
| id | params                  |
+----+-------------------------+
|  1 | params test abc & xyz 1 |
|  2 | params test abc & xyz 2 |
|  3 | params test abc & xyz 3 |
+----+-------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and it works for me...

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir, but
1 - I know that I have 139 rows containing the string "abc/xyz" for the specific alias (myalias)
2- searching only for params "abc" or "xyz" the result is 139 rows
3- searching only for alias "myalias"  the result is 139 rows
4- searching ONLY for "abc/xyz"  the result is 0 rows
I think that the foward-slash (/) is causing me some trouble that I don't recognize.

Comment: @Znort I've provide some example... Not sure that it will help you, but I just trying to reproduce your problem...

Comment: Thank's @Vladimir for trying and +1 for to demonstrate that normaly the foward-slash don't affect the query. I edited my question for more clarity.